# python mathplotlib savefig FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib, anaconda

I've made a figure using matplotlib and now I'm trying to save it to file using matplotlib.pyplot.savefig

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# . . .

plt.savefig("/home/username/PycharmProjects/sandbox/images/result.png")
```

Directory "/home/username/PycharmProjects/sandbox/images/" exists, but unfortunately it occurs FileNotFoundError at plt.savefig call.

Does anybody know, how can this problem be solved?

Comment: It is very likely that the directory does *not* exist. Triple check for any typos or other simple oversights.

Comment: I've pentachecked it using terminal. I've also tried plt.savefig('result.png') hoping that file will be saved to directory which is considered to be current, but this way also doesn't work.

Comment: And can you write normally into that directory from Python. That is, with `with open(<full path>, "w") as fp: fp.write("random")`?

Comment: Yes, your write expression works correcty and my plt.savefig fails with the same file path :(

Comment: Hi! I'm a bit late! I had the same problem, in my case there were some "special" character inside the name. In particular there were a " / ".

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the problem was the leading `/`. So the following should work:

```
plt.savefig("home/username/PycharmProjects/sandbox/images/result.png")
```

Answer (score 3):

Most errors related to saving files and plots can be prevented by

- plotting the graph,
- building the path to the save directory without hard coding it into a string,
- saving the plot.

Independent of your operating system, you can get the current directory your python script is running and from there, you can save your file in that directory or create a subfolder in this location to save your file in. Both implementations are described below using the `os library`.

## Import required libraries

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

## Plot the graph

```
X = [_ for _ in range(100)]
plt.plot(X)
plt.title('A plot of 1st 100 numbers')
```

## Get current working directory path

```
current_directory_path = os.getcwd()
file_name = 'result.png'
```

> This gets the path to the current directory's path you
> are running the python script from. No need to hard code the path
> yourself which could result in errors in most cases if you forgot to
> escape special characters or appropriate slashes for your OS.

## Build file_path to save in the current working directory

```
file_path = os.path.join(current_directory_path, file_name)
```

> In windows, you get something like `c:\\Users\\...\\result.png`.
> This may differ in linux.

## Build file_path to save plot in a subfolder

```
subfolder_path = os.path.join(current_directory_path, 'subfolder')

if not os.path.exists(subfolder_path):
    os.makedirs(subfolder_path)

file_path = os.path.join(subfolder_path, file_name)
```

> The above checks if 'subfolder' directory exists in the current
> directory if not, creates it. In windows, you get something like
> `c:\\Users\\...\\subfolder\\result.png'`

## Save the plot

```
plt.savefig(file_path)
```

Finally, file is saved to the specified file_path with no errors.